# Not able to extract the link in node "<enc:enclosure rdf:resource..." from xml file with PHP

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, rss, simplexml

currently I'd like to parse a string from a xml-file (RSS) to retrieve and display the image link in node: "<enc:enclosure rdf:resource="https://www.science.org/... .jpg".
To me it looks like something with two different namespaces in it. And so far I found no similar question or example to get this working.
In attached simplified code example you can see what is working as expected and that the link in node : "<enc:enclosure rdf:resource="https://www.science.org/... .jpg" is not displayed that way.

```
<?php
$xml_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/basic/2.0/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:enc="http://purl.oclc.org/net/rss_2.0/enc/" xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/" xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/">
<item>
      <title><![CDATA[Canada moves to ban funding for ‘risky’ foreign collaborations]]></title>
      <link>https://www.science.org/content/article/canada-moves-ban-funding-risky-foreign-collaborations</link>
      <description><![CDATA[China is seen as main target in rejecting joint projects with certain foreign entities]]></description>
      <enc:enclosure rdf:resource="https://www.science.org/do/10.1126/science.adh2317/rss/_20230217_nid_canada_china.jpg" enc:length="165061" enc:type="image/jpeg" />
      <dc:title><![CDATA[Canada moves to ban funding for ‘risky’ foreign collaborations]]></dc:title>
      <dc:identifier>doi:10.1126/science.adh2317</dc:identifier>
      <dc:date>2023-02-17T05:55:00Z</dc:date>
      <dc:creator>Jeffrey Mervis</dc:creator>
      <prism:publicationName><![CDATA[Canada moves to ban funding for ‘risky’ foreign collaborations]]></prism:publicationName>
      <prism:coverDate>2023-02-17T05:55:00Z</prism:coverDate>
      <prism:coverDisplayDate>2023-02-17T05:55:00Z</prism:coverDisplayDate>
      <prism:doi>10.1126/science.adh2317</prism:doi>
      <prism:url>https://www.science.org/content/article/canada-moves-ban-funding-risky-foreign-collaborations</prism:url>
</item></rdf:RDF>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);

foreach ($xml->item as $item) {
if($item->children('http://purl.oclc.org/net/rss_2.0/enc/')) {
foreach ($item->children('http://purl.oclc.org/net/rss_2.0/enc/') as $eintrag1) {
echo'<pre>';print_r($eintrag1);echo'</pre>'; // is working  
echo 'Length: ' . $eintrag1['length'] . '<br />'; // is working
$eintrag2 = $eintrag1->children('http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#');
echo'<pre>';print_r($eintrag2);echo'</pre>'; // is working
echo 'Resource: ' . $eintrag2['resource'] . '<br />'; // NOT working!!! Only empty output, but it's the link I would like to extract!
} }
}
?>
```

It looks simple and I thought I already managed those problems with my few PHP skills but none of my approaches (f.e. DOM, SimpleXML, xpath) brought me to the desired result.
If someone finds time to help me finding the answer I would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can you [edit] in a simplified version of the XML you're accessing (testing to make sure it still behaves the same as the real thing)? That way, the question remains valid even if the data at the other end of the link changes, and it's easier to copy the example to answers. Also, try to be more specific about the expected and actual output.

Answer (score 2):

SimpleXML does some implicit namespace switching. You used the explicit syntax for the children already, you can do the same for the attributes.

However I suggest defining a constant/variable with all the namespaces you are using. This will make you code a lot more readable. The keys can be the different from the prefixes in the document.

```php
$xmlns = [
    'enc' => 'http://purl.oclc.org/net/rss_2.0/enc/',
    'rdf' => 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#',
    // defined in the XML as namespace for elements without a prefix
    'rss' => 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/',
];

$rdf = simplexml_load_string(getXMLString());

foreach ($rdf->children($xmlns['rss'])->item as $item) {
    foreach ($item->children($xmlns['enc'])->enclosure as $enclosure) {
        echo 'Length: ' . $enclosure->attributes($xmlns['enc'])['length'] . "\n"; 
        echo 'Resource: ' . $enclosure->attributes($xmlns['rdf'])['resource'] . "\n"; 
    } 
}

function getXMLString() {
    return <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/basic/2.0/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:enc="http://purl.oclc.org/net/rss_2.0/enc/" xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/" xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/">
<item>
      <title><![CDATA[Canada moves to ban funding for ‘risky’ foreign collaborations]]></title>
      <link>https://www.science.org/content/article/canada-moves-ban-funding-risky-foreign-collaborations</link>
      <description><![CDATA[China is seen as main target in rejecting joint projects with certain foreign entities]]></description>
      <enc:enclosure rdf:resource="https://www.science.org/do/10.1126/science.adh2317/rss/_20230217_nid_canada_china.jpg" enc:length="165061" enc:type="image/jpeg" />
      <dc:title><![CDATA[Canada moves to ban funding for ‘risky’ foreign collaborations]]></dc:title>
      <dc:identifier>doi:10.1126/science.adh2317</dc:identifier>
      <dc:date>2023-02-17T05:55:00Z</dc:date>
      <dc:creator>Jeffrey Mervis</dc:creator>
      <prism:publicationName><![CDATA[Canada moves to ban funding for ‘risky’ foreign collaborations]]></prism:publicationName>
      <prism:coverDate>2023-02-17T05:55:00Z</prism:coverDate>
      <prism:coverDisplayDate>2023-02-17T05:55:00Z</prism:coverDisplayDate>
      <prism:doi>10.1126/science.adh2317</prism:doi>
      <prism:url>https://www.science.org/content/article/canada-moves-ban-funding-risky-foreign-collaborations</prism:url>
</item></rdf:RDF>
XML;
}
```

Output:

```
Length: 165061
Resource: https://www.science.org/do/10.1126/science.adh2317/rss/_20230217_nid_canada_china.jpg
```

#### DOM

DOM is more explicit and has a set of namespace aware methods with the suffix `NS` (for example `getAttributeNS()`).

`DOMXpath::evaluate()` allows for complex expressions to fetch nodes and scalar values:

```php
$xmlns = [
    'enc' => 'http://purl.oclc.org/net/rss_2.0/enc/',
    'rdf' => 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#',
    // defined in the XML as namespace for elements without a prefix
    'rss' => 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/',
];

$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->loadXML(getXMLString());
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
// register the namespaces 
foreach ($xmlns as $alias => $uri) {
    $xpath->registerNamespace($alias, $uri);
}
$items = [];
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//rss:item') as $itemNode) {
    $items[] = [
        // fetch "{http://purl.org/rss/1.0/}title" as string
        'title' => $xpath->evaluate('string(rss:title)', $itemNode),
        'enclosure' => [
            // fetch the attribute values
            'resource' => $xpath->evaluate('string(enc:enclosure/@rdf:resource)', $itemNode),
            'length' => $xpath->evaluate('number(enc:enclosure/@enc:length)', $itemNode)
        ],
    ];
}
var_dump($items);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(66) "Canada moves to ban funding for ‘risky’ foreign collaborations"
    ["enclosure"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["resource"]=>
      string(85) "https://www.science.org/do/10.1126/science.adh2317/rss/_20230217_nid_canada_china.jpg"
      ["length"]=>
      float(165061)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and understandable answer. It made the whole thing a lot clearer to me.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXML is known to have issues with namespaces, try DOM + DOMXPath instead

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML(file_get_contents('https://www.science.org/rss/news_current.xml'));
$dxp = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($dxp->query('//enc:enclosure') as $enclosure) {
    echo 'Resource: ' . $enclosure->getAttribute('rdf:resource') . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: SimpleXML absolutely does not have "issues with namespaces"; all it has "issues" with is `print_r` and similar functions (which you don't actually _need_ to use). You should also _not_ rely on someone else's namespace prefixes (like "enc:" and "rdf:") - the same XML generated by a slightly different piece of software might have different prefixes for the same namespaces, and this code will completely break. If you do use XPath, you should use `registerNamespace` to choose your own prefixes, as shown in [the answer by ThW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75523795/157957).

Comment: I'm not that deep into that matter, so I'm thankful for every explanation. I even can not really judge what ist cleaner programmed and what's not. The first answer from Kazz came just up really fast and worked for me, so I was satisfied.